# template lookup issues. What am i not understanding?

Tags: python, mako, python-3.3

**Background:**

I have the following directory structure:

```
/absolute/path/to/templates
            components/
                   component1.mak
                   component2.mak
            template1.mak
```

The plan is for the templates in the template directory to `include` a bunch of components.

in template1.mak I have something like:

```
 <%include file="xxx.mak"/>
```

where `xxx` is either `components/component1.mak` or just `component1.mak` (I tried both with different results, detailed below)

```
mylookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[yyy,])
oTemplate = Template(filename='/path/to/templates/template1.mak', lookup=mylookup)
oTemplate.render(args)
```

where yyy is either `'/absolute/path/to/templates'` or `'/absolute/path/to/templates/components'`

**The Problem:**

No matter what combination of xxx and yyy values I use I get a template lookup exception. The value of yyy (the lookup path) doesn't seem to have any effect of the exception.

If xxx (the include tag path) is `'components\component1.mak'` the error says it can't find the file `/absolute/path/to/templates/components/component1.mak`. And if `xxx` is just `'component1.mak'` then the error is it can't find  `/absolute/path/to/templates/component1.mak`.

**The Question**

How can I get mako to  include the stuff in the components directory? And what am I missing or not understanding about template lookup?

Comment: Have you tried this with a leading `/` when defining your xxx call in the template?  Or using raw strings in your python code?

Comment: @bdiamante: That did the trick :) Post it as an answer so I can give you some points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting a leading `/` when defining your xxx call in the template.

Comment: Could you share a full, working example? Trying to get my head around the Mako templating but it's not awfully simple :)

Comment: This little quirk stumped my project for the last few hours. Thanks for sharing this tip!

For those wondering what you actually do: Simply add a leading `/` to the template name in your include statement (like this - `<%include file="/xxx.mako" />`

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to provide a more informative answer - the path is really depends on which file executed the code.

### example 1

```
web/file.cgi              // was called first from the web
web/templates/header.mako // was called somewhere in file.cgi
```

In this case, the lookup dir should be:

```
mylookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['templates/'])
```

### example 2

```
// was called first from the web
web/file.cgi                 

// was imported and called in file.cgi
../somewhere/in-PYTHONPATH/mymodules/modulename.py

// was called from modulename.py
../somewhere/in-PYTHONPATH/mymodules/templates/edit.html
```

Then your lookup dir should actually be:

```
 mylookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['../../../../somewhere/in-PYTHONPATH/mymodules/templates/'])
 OR
 mylookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['/fullpath/to/somewhere/in-PYTHONPATH/mymodules/templates/'])
```

You needed the fullpath because `web/file.cgi` isn't located in a relative path with the modules in the backend ...

As for some reason, Mako Templates doesn't know to lookup in the relative directory to the `mymodules/modulename.py` file of where it called the `mymodules/templates/edit.html` not sure why ( or maybe it's just my older version of Mako Templates )

The `<%include file="xxx.mak"/>` though, behave different, as it does looking up relativly to where the file is found, this is why the `/` pulled it a one level up - and then it looked into `templates/` .. but it again, it doesn't work the same for modules somewhere in the server ....

hope it helps others ...